# cakephp 2 apps with shared core

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 CakePHP applications. They are located on same server, on 2 different ports (80 and 1112)

How to config them to use 1 shared Cake core? (please send a complete guide, if it is possible for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can place your app folder where your webserver requires it. Place cake folder where you need it to be. Update app/webroot/index.php and app/webroot/test.php accordingly

- update `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'path' . DS . 'to'.DS.'cake_core'. DS. 'lib' );`

Those two files are well self documented.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to physically share the same folder.
using apache virtual host setup you can easily route them to two different domains

the setup would just be

```
 app1/
 app2/
 vendors/
 lib/Cake
```

Comment: could you post virtual host configuration example (for 2 apps on same domain and different ports)? I have problems and my apps will redirect together.

Comment: pretty much the same as the linux part of http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/ - you set them up using the app1 and app2 webroot paths.